# Can I use google aps login to authenticate users in FreeNAS?

Tags: ldap, g-suite, truenas

I want to setup FreeNAS as a central file repository for all my employees to access company related data. A lot of our infrastructure operates on Google Apps including Android phones. I would like to use the same login for them to access the files.

If it is not possible straight in FreeNAS, maybe Crowd could be used in between?
I have a license for Atlassian Crowd, which should be able to authenticate users using Google Apps and act as LDAP server. It seems so.

I'm not really looking for someone to hand me over a tutorial on how to do this from start to end, I would just like to know if this is even possible, or am I going to waste my time trying to build something that won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Apps support LDAP sync by using [Google Apps Directory Sync](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=106368) and [Google Apps Password Sync](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2611859).

FreeNAS also supports LDAP.

So there you have it. Just use whatever LDAP service you like.